# The role of 2-nitrophenol in tin etchant (aqueous mixture of 2-nitrophenol and NaOH)

Tags: acid-base, metal, metallurgy

Aqueous mixture of 2-nitrophenol and NaOH is a time-honored etchant that dissolves tin-rich alloy and retain the intermetallic compounds from the tin. I wonder the role of 2-nitrophenol in the etching reaction and the purposes of adding 2-nitrophenol. Could anyone shed some light on this question?

**Some research using such etchant**

Silver, J., C. A. Mackay, and J. D. Donaldson. "A systematic investigation of the Mössbauer parameters of some intermetallic compounds and electroplated alloys of tin." Journal of Materials Science 11.5 (1976): 836-842.

Zeng, Guang, et al. "Kinetics of the polymorphic phase transformation of Cu6Sn5." Acta materialia 69 (2014): 135-148.

Comment: My intuition is 2-nitrophenol prevent intermetallic compounds from dissolution, but, how?